# Get count of a column as well as value of column with specific condition for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, count, group-by

I 'am using sqlserver 2012 ,

I have table that contains column1 and column2  and other columns ,

I want  to get count of column1 as well as  the value of column2 that matches  specific condition  **for each group**

> the condition is column2 like '%page1%'

```
select  COUNT(column1)  FROM MyTable  group by column1
```

> what  should I add to this query .

Thanks in advance .....

Answer (score 0):

Use CASE WHEN condition inside COUNT:

```
SELECT 
totC1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN column1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ,
totC2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN column2 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ,
totC3 = COUNT(CASE WHEN column3 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ,
totC4 = COUNT(CASE WHEN column4 > 0 OR YourCondition = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

In this way if the condition is verified the item will be counted otherwise no.

Let me know